# Pandas not clearing underscore / hidden variables from memory

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big dataset, around ~2GB that I load into Pandas' DataFrame. Whenever I try to perform some sort of operation on it, say filtering, it seems to create a new copy in memory even though I'm not saving it in any variable. For example Say I want to filter 'ID' column:
**df[df['ID'].str.len() == 11]**- Pandas automatically creates some variable (name starting with underscore) and stores it there, but it doesn't seem to get cleared automatically. So after I do few similar operations to just explore the data, my memory is already full and it gives me an error. So my question is:

1. Is there a way to filter the data, without creating a copy? Or just create and instantly delete it if I'm not saving it in a variable?
2. If not, is there a command to clear pandas' generated variables? Only thing I found working is just checking the memory and deleting variables by hand, but it still doesn't seem to fully clear the memory.

I'm attaching the picture of how memory looks, df is my dataframe, every other is auto generated.
[image]

Comment: This is not `pandas`, it's your interactive shell/notebook that generates those as a pointer to the last result(s)

Comment: @mozway Oh, that makes much more sense. In that case, is there a way to prevent it / workaround ?

Comment: Hi, what happens with `import builtins` then `del builtins._`?